# Map F2 to NEERDTreeToggle

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want just to open and close NERDTree, pushing the <kbd>F2</kbd> button. I've mapped it in this way  :

```
map <silent>  <F2> NERDTreeToggle
```

But, Actually this doesn't work properly and I haven't understood why...

Comment: `nmap <silent> <F2> :execute 'NERDTreeToggle ' . getcwd()<CR>`

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thanks... But can you explain me why you needed to add  . getcwd()<CR>

Comment: The `<CR>` is the necessary bit.  It just means hit the Enter key to execute the command.  But: `nmap <silent> <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` will do.

Comment: `getcwd()` is used to set working directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my config for NERDTree.

```
silent! nmap <C-p> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
silent! map <F3> :NERDTreeFind<CR>

let g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode="<F3>"
let g:NERDTreeMapPreview="<F4>"
```

`F3` will open NERDTree panel and highlight current file. 
And when you're in the NERDTree panel, `F3` will open file under cursor. 
So, I can use one button to jump between buffer and NERDTree.
(And `F4` for preview because it's next to `F3`)

Comment: Is there a way to get the same behavior but open the file inder cursor in a split or vertical split?

Comment: C-W v, C-W s. Here is a good answer http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/open-filename-under-cursor-like-gf-but-in-a-new-tab-or-split

Comment: turns out it can be done very easily with let g:NERDTreeMapOpenSplit="<F3>".

Answer (score 10):

your mapping:

`map <silent>  <F2> NERDTreeToggle`

should be:

`map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

I think you'll find that'll work (you basically missed the colon and the `<CR>` to make the action happen...